# Link to an anchor within JQuery tabbed content via URL hash

Tags: jquery, anchor, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs, hashtag

I've seen some good threads on similar topics but none that help me deal directly with the chunk of code I have to work with which I'll share below. This is a tabbed area which now allows to go to a tab from a URL hash tag. However, I am adding jump links within tabs and need to be able to share a URL to specific anchors within tabs. The JS in question is this:

```
if(window.location.hash && document.getElementById(window.location.hash.split('#')[1]) && $('#'+window.location.hash.split('#')[1]).closest('div.outer').length > 0){
        var pane = $('#'+window.location.hash.split('#')[1]);
        pane.closest('div.outer').find('ul.outertabs li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(pane.closest('div.outer').find('ul.outertabs li')[pane.index()]).addClass('selected');
        pane.closest('div.outer').find('div.pane').hide();
        pane.show();
    }
```

Thanks in advance. If this is not enough info let me know.